# I have 5 checkboxes may i have to select one or more and save into table

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008-r2

this is my ms sql server table

```
create table tblAdd_Subject ( 
S_ID int identity(100,1)primary key,
Subject1 varchar(50), 
Subject2 varchar(50), 
Subject3 varchar(50), 
Subject4 varchar(50), 
Subject5 varchar(50));
```

i have 5 checkboxes may i have to select 1 or more checkbox and click on save button it is C# win form application

Comment: is that 5 individual check boxes or a checkbox list? anyway the question doesn't contains necessary information, could you please be more clear

Comment: A CheckBox knows *true* and *false* and maybe *not set*... Is there a reason to declare your columns as `VARCHAR(50)`? Are you just wanting to store five unrelated check states in on table row?

Comment: i am working on visual studio 2010 if i  select 1 or more checkboxes and click on save button i want to save only  checked data in tblAdd_Subject

Comment: for example in these 5 checkboxes i want to select only 1 3 and 5 so the other rows should insert empty in tblAdd_Subject

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you need something like this.

```
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("[your connection string goes here]");
    connection.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tblAdd_Subject(Subject1, Subject2, Subject3, Subject4, Subject5) values(@Subject1, @Subject2, @Subject3, @Subject4, @Subject5)", connection);

    cmd.Parameters.Clear();
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Subject1", chk1.Checked ? "some value for subject 1" : string.Empty);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Subject2", chk2.Checked ? "some value for subject 2" : string.Empty);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Subject3", chk3.Checked ? "some value for subject 3" : string.Empty);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Subject4", chk4.Checked ? "some value for subject 4" : string.Empty);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Subject5", chk5.Checked ? "some value for subject 5" : string.Empty);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Thamk You Nino Dude and shnugo dude i have got this is really good example

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Next time, please try to write a bit more about your problem, so people could give you better answer :)

Comment: i have two tables i want to generate PDF of 1 row in c# winform using msSql